# Structure of legacy project with Silex

Tags: php, silex, legacy-code

I have a very old flat PHP project. I would like to modernize the source files without changing the big and old database structure. I found the PHP Framework Symfony Silex. I like the micro structure of this framework it's not so complicated to understand.

I have the following file structure:

```
- classes (The business logic)
- web (index.php and all my controllers)
- vendors
```

- How can I include my business logic from the Silex app? Should I use `require_once('classes/file1.php');` in my `index.php`?
- How can I access the database from the business logic files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitioning legacy code to a new framework is a difficult task. It's not going to be as simple as requiring your business logic files. Here's how I would go about it if I were in your position.

Spend some time **learning Silex**. Start by building a brand new test project with it to see how it works. It's best if you know how the framework is *supposed* to work before you try to integrate it with a legacy system. After you've tried it for a while, you can decide if Silex is a good fit for you.

Once you know how Silex works, you should get the **Composer autoloader** working with your code. Composer can load you business logic classes without having to use `require`.

Next, figure out how to work with your **database**. I see two options for you. You can either transition to Doctrine, or use your existing database access classes. The Symfony (and therefore Silex) ecosystem is oriented around the Doctrine ORM. Depending on your schema, you may be able to write Doctrine mappings for it. However, Silex is not tied to Doctrine, and you should be able to use your existing database access code. If you keep your existing system, you'll probably want to write a Silex `ServiceProvider` to integrate with it.

Next, the hardest part is probably going to be moving your business logic to Silex **controllers**. One thing to keep in mind is that you don't necessarily need to transition your entire project at once. Depending on how big your project is, you may want to transition a piece at a time.

Comment: I have one more question. If i use my bussiness logic as Services and if i need to access the database in my Service. Is it the right way to access the database to pass the "$app['db']" into the constructor of my service? I will try to use "DoctrineServiceProvider" in my first steps.

Comment: Yes. That's right. The Silex way to do that would be to create a service providers for your Service classes. That's where you would construct your services and pass `$app['db']` into their constructors.